# Externalize application-prod.yml

Tags: jhipster

In jhipster what is the simple and best way to externalize application-prod.yml? We run it via java -jar app.jar in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a config dir next to the .jar, and then save the .yml in that directory, like config/application-prod.yml

Spring Boot will load the properties from there.

> SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files
>   in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:
>
> ```
> A /config subdirectory of the current directory
>
> The current directory
>
> A classpath /config package
>
> The classpath root
> ```
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations
>   higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).